# Правильно использование cookies для сохранения авторизации

Tags: php, cookie

Как правильно сделать cookies для запоминания пользователя. Как я понимаю: 
 По желанию пользователя ставим ему cookies, которая является например (login + salt + time()) и хешируем это в SHA-512 и заносим эту запись в БД и на каждой странице сравниваем значения cookies и значения в БД и выбираем пользователя из БД по этому хешу. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Как успехи? У меня такая же задача,пока не решил как слелать.

Answer (score 0):

По соображениям безопасности я бы еще привязал хеш к IP адресу с которого идет запрос и может быть к юзер агенту. То есть при проверке хеша также сверяется IP с которого пришел запрос. Плюс надо учесть возможность логина сразу с нескольких устройств, то есть для одного пользователя может быть несколько хешей.
А еще больше подробностей есть тут https://david-m.livejournal.com/1267236.html